# how to use MvcMiniProfiler with MvcTurbine?

Tags: c#, structuremap, mvc-mini-profiler

I am using MvcTurbine which automatically wires up the `IViewEngines` from your project and I recently added MvcMiniProfiler and am trying to get it to work the only problem is that the MvcMiniProfiler has a ProfilingViewEngine which requires a constructor argument for IViewEngine so it creates a Bidirectional Dependancy in Structuremap.   Below is the error

```
StructureMap Exception Code:  295
Bidirectional Dependency Problem detected with RequestedType: 
System.Web.Mvc.IViewEngine, Name: a8cb1f76-6ff5-4702-9e7a-3200703dd519, ConcreteType: MvcMiniProfiler.MVCHelpers.ProfilingViewEngine.  
The BuildStack is:
1.) RequestedType: System.Web.Mvc.IViewEngine, Name: a8cb1f76-6ff5-4702-9e7a-3200703dd519, ConcreteType: MvcMiniProfiler.MVCHelpers.ProfilingViewEngine
```

How do you ignore or manually register IViewEngines with MvcTurbine?

Comment: interesting question, keep in mind the view engine interception is totally optional, you could "possibly" have turbine call back to mini profiler.

Comment: As a note I do have this working by clearing out the IViewEnginges from Turbine but MVCTurbine ideally needs a way to specify which IViewEngines to wireup and not to wire all of them up.  Hopefully when this is added I will answer the question.(What I have is more of a hack)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by overriding the IViewEngine registration process and explicitly set a single IViewEngine implementation.

In my global.asax, I added the following:

`Engine.Initialize.DisableViewEngineRegistration();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();`

This forced MvcTurbine to use the razor view engine, which the MvcMiniProfiler could override without error.

I hope that this helps after so long. If not for you, then maybe for others like myself that found your question as the only resource on this issue.